# How to use Python PedalBoard to add reverb to PyAudio stream

Tags: python, numpy, audio

Using this glorious library [PedalBoard](https://github.com/spotify/pedalboard).
Setting up AudioStream and adding effects is pretty easy:

```
with AudioStream(
  input_device_name="MacBook Air Microphone",
  output_device_name="MacBook Air Speakers",
  allow_feedback=True
) as stream:
```

But now how can we make AudioStream with effects from another stream source, like PyAudio:

```
# something like:
py_stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,channels=1)
with AudioStream( py_stream )
```

Comment: From the documentation https://spotify.github.io/pedalboard/reference/pedalboard.io.html#pedalboard.io.AudioStream I don’t believe you can take that approach: _**This class uses C++ under the hood to ensure speed, thread safety, and avoid any locking concerns with Python’s Global Interpreter Lock. Audio data processed by AudioStream is not available to Python code; the only way to interact with the audio stream is through the plugins attribute.**_ you will probably need too look at making the plugin interact with pyaudio rather than pyaudio interacting with the stream

Comment: If the AudioStream code is not available to Python I think it is safe to say Python is not available to AudioStream

Comment: Thanks for commenting. If you look carefully you will find this is indeed possible. We are waiting for a few more creative solutions.

Comment: I suppose if you ouput audio from pyaudio a loop back you could then open that stream via the [`AudioStream`](https://spotify.github.io/pedalboard/reference/pedalboard.io.html#pedalboard.io.AudioStream) interface. I am looking pretty closely and the only point of entry I can see to `AudioStream` from the docs is a named string `input_device_name: str` where the string is the interface name or from a [bytes "file-like" object](https://spotify.github.io/pedalboard/reference/pedalboard.io.html#pedalboard.io.AudioFile)

Comment: and PyAudio doesn't seem to provide a [raw pointer to the stream](https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/docs/#class-pyaudio-stream).

Comment: It would make more sense to just pass the sample data from the PyAudio to the [plugin](https://spotify.github.io/pedalboard/reference/pedalboard.html#pedalboard.Plugin) no? At best if you find a method to pass the buffer from pyaudio as a file stream it will still be round tripping to Pedal when you could just go straight to the source and operate on that date instead. I envisage there being some hefty overheads without the use of Cython.